# How can I have custom unhandled exception logging middleware with the developer exception page without duplicate log entries?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core

Here's [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem):

- My ASP.NET Core MVC + Web API application consumes other middleware layers like IdentityServer4 which use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` to write events (like authentication failure events).
- These events are currently written with minimal extra data making troubleshooting difficult. I want to add info like the HTTP request headers and path to help identify the cause of bad events.
- My research led me to using `ILogger<T>.BeginScope` to create a "scoped logger" middleware that lasts for the life of the ASP.NET Core HTTP request. This `using( logger.BeginScope( ... ) )` call would live in a Middleware (which works by affecting the DI `ILogger` of transient services).
- My middleware would **not** catch exceptions itself, only add to the logging scope, like so:

  ```
  class LoggingScopeMiddleware {

      private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory; // DI
      private readonly RequestDelegate next;

      public async Task Invoke( HttpContext context ) {

          Dictionary<String,Object> values = CreateDict( context.Request... );

          using( this.loggerFactory.CreateLogger().BeginScope( values ) ) {

              this.next( context );
          }

      }
  }
  ```
- However, if an exception is thrown inside `next` then when it is logged (by another middleware layer either higher-up or lower-down in the chain) then it will lose the extra logging values added in `BeginScope`. I thought this wasn't meant to happen, but it does.
- **I also want the Developer Exception Page to continue to work**
- If I do catch and log the exception inside my `LoggingScopeMiddleware.Invoke` method then the exception won't be caught by the Developer Exception page and I'll just get a blank page displayed in the browser.
- If I move the Developer Exception Page higher-up in the middleware chain I noticed that the exception is logged without any of the scoped properties.
- If I catch the exception inside my `LoggingScopeMiddleware` then I can log it with the extra properties:

  ```
  class ExceptionCatchingLoggingScopeMiddleware {

      private readonly ILoggerFactory  loggerFactory; // DI
      private readonly RequestDelegate next;
      private readonly Boolean         rethrow = true;

      public async Task Invoke( HttpContext context ) {

          Dictionary<String,Object> values = CreateDict( context.Request... );

          using( this.loggerFactory.CreateLogger().BeginScope( values ) ) {
              try {
                  this.next( context );
              } catch( Exception ex ) {
                  LogException( ex );
                  if( this.rethrow ) throw;
              } 
          }

      }
  }
  ```

  - But if I rethrow it then the exception is logged twice elsewhere in the middleware chain outside of my control (and this duplicate log entry doesn't include the extra properties). This also happens if I use the `when( LogException( ex ) /* == false */ )` trick in C# 6.0.
  - If I swallow the exception and don't rethrow it then the Developer Exception Page won't be invoked and I get blank output.

In summary:

- Scenario 1:

  - Middleware: `--> DeveloperExceptionPage --> LoggingScopeMiddleware -->`
  - Developer page: Displayed. (Good)
  - Unhandled exception: Logged without scoped properties. (Bad)
- Scenario 2:

  - Middleware: `--> LoggingScopeMiddleware --> DeveloperExceptionPage -->`
  - Developer page: Displayed. (Good)
  - Unhandled exception: Logged without scoped properties. (Bad)
- Scenario 3:

  - Middleware: `--> ExceptionCatchingLoggingScopeMiddleware --> DeveloperExceptionPage -->`
  - Developer page: Displayed. (Good)
  - Unhandled exception: Logged without scoped properties. (Bad)
- Scenario 4:

  - Middleware: `--> DeveloperExceptionPage --> ExceptionCatchingLoggingScopeMiddleware( rethrow: true ) -->`
  - Developer page: Displayed. (Good)
  - Unhandled exception: Logged twice, once with scoped properties (Good) and again without scoped properties (Bad)
- Scenario 5:

  - Middleware: `--> DeveloperExceptionPage --> ExceptionCatchingLoggingScopeMiddleware( rethrow: false ) -->`
  - Developer page: Not displayed. (Bad)
  - Unhandled exception: Logged once with scoped properties (Good)